# WPF - LibraryBar - Animation

Tags: wpf

Is there any way to animate or fade a LibraryBar? I want a Library Bar which isnt shown to 100 percent on normal use. I want a little bar at the bottom (maybe a part of the LibrarayBar). When the mouse or finger click on the bar (little part of the LibrarayBar) the whole bar should appear with a slow fade in or animation.
Anybody of you know how to this?

Sry fpr my English......

Answer (score 0):

You could write 2 routed event handlers for `GetFocus` and `LostFocus` events by declaring them as attributes of GetFocusEvent and LostFocusEvent (or `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`) depending on whether you want the glowing/dimming to happen with an explicit click or reactive to just "hovering".

These handlers would alter the `OpacityProperty` property.

To start "dimmed", you can adjust an initial value for the Opacity propert

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But can you give me a example?